# How to find out all dashboard schedules?

Tags: dashboard

User would like to know all existing dashboard refresh schedules if they were scheduled to refresh.

Comment: Hi Deb, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, or in your case what "User" and in what context, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the programmatic solutions above, you can find all Dashboard Refreshes by going to:

```
Setup | Monitoring | Scheduled Jobs
```

[image]

You can create a custom view that shows only Dashboard Refreshes as well

Answer (score 1):

I use queries for this. To do that I use Workbench workbench.developerforce.com/query.php. Select the environment and agree to the terms of service and click on Login with Salesforce. It will prompt you to login. In the gray bar under queries select "SOQL Queries". You will query CronTrigger with something like

```
SELECT CronJobDetailId,Id,NextFireTime,OwnerId,State FROM CronTrigger
```

Export this using the Bulk CSV option
Then you would query CronJobDetail with something like

```
SELECT Id,JobType,Name FROM CronJobDetail
```

Export this using the Bulk CSV option

Then query Dashboards with something like

```
SELECT Description,FolderId,Id,RunningUserId,Title,Type FROM Dashboard WHERE isdeleted=false
```

Export this using the Bulk CSV option

In Excel use VLookup to match the CronJobDetail Id column of the CronTrigger table with the ID column of the CronJobDetail table to return the Name field of the CronJobDetail table to the CronTrigger table. Use VLookup again for the same fields to return the JobType value from the CronJobDetail table to the CronTrigger table. Then you will go to the dashboards table and use a formula to remove the last 3 characters from the Id. Then use that new Id value to match with the Name field that was returned to the CronTrigger table in the steps above and return the Title of the dashboard to the CronTrigger table. This sounds long but it is pretty short and that way you get a clean report with the name of the dashboard and the refresh information. If you run into any issues you can comment and I can provide additional details.

Comment: @Deb You're very welcome. Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 0):

You can query this kind of informations with SOQL and then show them via VisualForce page.

```
List<CronTrigger> CronTriggers = 
    [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Id
     FROM CronTrigger 
     WHERE CronJobDetail.JobType = '3' 
     ORDER BY CreatedDate];

List<Id> listID = new List<Id>();
for ( CronTrigger detailID : CronTriggers) {
    listID.add(detailID.CronJobDetail.Id);   
}

List<CronJobDetail> details = [
    SELECT Id,JobType,Name FROM CronJobDetail 
    WHERE id IN :listID
];

List<Dashboard> listDash = [SELECT Description,FolderId,Id,RunningUserId,Title,Type 
                            FROM Dashboard 
                            WHERE isdeleted=false
                            ORDER BY CreatedDate
                            ];

List<Dashboard> finalResults = new List<Dashboard>();
for (CronJobDetail detail : details) {
    for (Dashboard dash : listDash) {
        if ( detail.Name == String.valueOf(dash.id).Substring(0,String.valueOf(dash.id).length()-3)) {
            finalResults.add(dash);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will definitely give it a try at a later time. Thanks for your help.